# What is the correct movement speed for crawling, running, etc.?

Tags: movement, twilight-2000, twilight-2000-2.2

In Twilight 2000, character creation includes crawl/walk/trot/run, but both in combat and travel these are supplanted by other values (e.g. a character could have a crawl speed of 3 but will crawl at 2 meters a turn according to the rulebook description of a crawl action).

Is this just an oversight, or are the alternate move speeds intended to be used in some other context, which I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 meters/turn crawl speed I can find referenced under **Combat Movement** along with **crawl/walk/trot/run** being listed as actions a character can perform in a combat round.  However, I can find no reference to the crawl speed of 3, that you mention.  The only other reference I can find for movement of men is 20/20 (on-road/off-road) from the **Travel Movement Table** of the **Referee's Charts**.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. A character creation aid I found had formulas for calculating movement rates, but I don't see it on the actual character sheet or the worksheet in the rulebook itself. It must be something that someone carried over from 2.0 or houseruled in.